# How to save recorded video using AVAssetWriter?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I tried many other blogs and stack overflow. I didn't get solution for this, I can able to create custom camera with preview. I need video with custom frame, that's why I am using AVAssetWriter. But i unable to save recorded video into documents.  I tried like this,

```
-(void) initilizeCameraConfigurations {

if(!captureSession) {

    captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [captureSession beginConfiguration];
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor;
    CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:captureSession];
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.bounds = self.view.frame;
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.controlsBgView];
}


// Add input to session
NSError *err;
videoCaptureDeviceInput  = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoCaptureDevice error:&err];

if([captureSession canAddInput:videoCaptureDeviceInput]) {
    [captureSession addInput:videoCaptureDeviceInput];
}

docPathUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[self getDocumentsUrl]];

assetWriter = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:docPathUrl fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&err];
NSParameterAssert(assetWriter);
//assetWriter.movieFragmentInterval = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, 1000);

NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:300], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:300], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               nil];




 writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];
 writerInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
 writerInput.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

 NSDictionary *sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:300], kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:300], kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
 nil];

 assetWriterPixelBufferInput = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary];


 if([assetWriter canAddInput:writerInput]) {
 [assetWriter addInput:writerInput];
 }

     // Set video stabilization mode to preview layer
AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode stablilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeCinematic;
if([videoCaptureDevice.activeFormat isVideoStabilizationModeSupported:stablilizationMode]) {
    [captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection setPreferredVideoStabilizationMode:stablilizationMode];
}


// image output
stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];
[captureSession addOutput:stillImageOutput];

[captureSession commitConfiguration];
if (![captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection isEnabled]) {
    [captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection setEnabled:YES];
}
[captureSession startRunning];

}
-(IBAction)startStopVideoRecording:(id)sender {

if(captureSession) {
    if(isVideoRecording) {
        [writerInput markAsFinished];

        [assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
            NSLog(@"Finished writing...checking completion status...");
            if (assetWriter.status != AVAssetWriterStatusFailed && assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusCompleted)
            {
                // Video saved
            } else
            {
                NSLog(@"#123 Video writing failed: %@", assetWriter.error);
            }

        }];

    } else {

        [assetWriter startWriting];
        [assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
        isVideoRecording = YES;

    }
}
}
-(NSString *) getDocumentsUrl {

NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
docPath = [[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Movie"] stringByAppendingString:@".mov"];
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:docPath]) {
    NSError *err;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:docPath error:&err];
}
NSLog(@"Movie path : %@",docPath);
return docPath;


}


@end
```

Correct me if anything wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what actually goes wrong, but two things look wrong with your code:

```
docPath = [[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Movie"] stringByAppendingString:@".mov"];
```

looks like it creates an undesired path like this `@"/path/Movie/.mov"`, when you want this:

```
docPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Movie.mov"];
```

And your timeline is wrong. Your asset writer starts at time 0, but the `sampleBuffer`s start at `CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimestamp(sampleBuffer) > 0`, so instead do this:

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    if(firstSampleBuffer) {
        [assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimestamp(sampleBuffer)];
    }

    [writerInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

}
```

Comment: I don't have any issue with document path. I think "didOutputSampleBuffer" use for "AVCaptureVideoOutput" that's why it won't call because we are using AVAssetWriter. We are providing docPath to asset writer to save video. we just call start and finish to asset writer. I don't have clear clarity on it. Can you provide clear picture on it.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, you have to main functional areas: One that generates video frames – this the `AVCaptureSession`, and everything that is attached to it –, and another that writes these frames to a file – in your case the `AVAssetWriter` with attached inputs.
The problem with your code is: There is no connection between these two. No video frames / images coming out of the capture session are passed to the asset writer inputs.

Furthermore, the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` method `-captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:` is nowhere called, so the capture session actually produces no frames.

So, as a minimum, implement something like this:

```
-(IBAction)captureStillImageAndAppend:(id)sender
{
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:stillImageOutput.connections.firstObject completionHandler:
        ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError* error)
        {
            // check error, omitted here
            if (CMTIME_IS_INVALID( startTime)) // startTime is an ivar
                [assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:(startTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp( imageDataSampleBuffer))];
            [writerInput appendSampleBuffer:imageDataSampleBuffer];
        }];
}
```

Remove the `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`, it's not used.

But there are issues with `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`:

- it's only intended to produce still images, not videos
- it must be configured to produce uncompressed sample buffers if the asset writer input is configured to compress the appended sample buffers (`stillImageOutput.outputSettings = @{ (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange)};`)
- it's deprecated under iOS

If you actually want to produce a video, as opposed to a sequence of still images, instead of the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` add a `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to the capture session. It needs a delegate and a serial dispatch queue to output the sample buffers. The delegate has to implement something like this:

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput*)output didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*)connection
{
    if (CMTIME_IS_INVALID( startTime)) // startTime is an ivar
        [assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:(startTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp( sampleBuffer))];
    [writerInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
}
```

Note that

- you will want to make sure that the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` only outputs frames when you're actually recording; add/remove it from the capture session or enable/disable its connection in the startStopVideoRecording action
- reset the `startTime` to `kCMTimeInvalid` before starting another recording

Comment: Thank you for response. It's working good and video also saving into documents folder. But it automatically stopped calling "didOutputSampleBuffer" after 2 seconds and started calling "didDropSampleBuffer". How to know cause of that issue and fix it?

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate/1388468-captureoutput?language=objc) for `-captureOutput:didDropSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`. It explains how to extract the reason from the passed in sample buffer with the `kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_DroppedFrameReason` attachment.

Comment: I can able to find the reason. It's always returning kCMSampleBufferDroppedFrameReason_OutOfBuffers after 2 seconds. How to overcome this. It's automatically getting stops after two seconds. I couldn't get solution for this. Can you suggest me the solution?

Comment: The most obvious reason for this would be retaining/keeping a permanent reference to the sample buffer passed to `didOutputSampleBuffer`. Do you do anything beyond appending it to the input as shown above?

Comment: A more subtle reason would be the asset writer not being able to handle (compress) the passed in buffer fast enough, e.g. when the cpu or gpu are under load. You did set the `expectsMediaDataInRealTime` of the writer input to YES, right? Otherwise, you may have to adjust output settings; note that `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` has two `-recommended...` methods which will provide optimized settings

Comment: Do you do anything beyond appending it to the input as shown above?    No. I just appending sample buffer to writer input. Once I stop recording saving video into documents. I watched WWDC also on AVFoundation, they also appending sample buffer to writer input.

Comment: Then you may have to do some profiling. On an iPad 3rd Gen., which seems to be pretty weak performance wise at this point, i generally see a few dropped frames (< 10) at the start of a recording, but then it will recorded without dropped frames until i hit stop.  Btw., may i kindly suggest you're posting this as a new questions, so it will reach a wider audience?

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for great support.